# How is Alexa programmed to sing?

Tags: audio, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

If you say "Alexa, sing for me", she will choose one of *several* songs that have been created with her voice. The voice(s) for each of these songs must have been created somehow.

At first, I thought that SSML would provide the tools necessary to do this, especially the [`<prosody>` tag](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#prosody) which has parameters for `pitch` and `rate` (duration).

I thought perhaps each syllable of singing could have its pronunciation specified with `<phoneme>` and its pitch and duration specified with `<prosody>`, with `<break>` tags in between:

```xml
<speak>
  <prosody rate="20%">
    <phoneme alphabet="x-sampa" ph="U">oo</phoneme>
    <break strength="none" />
  </prosody>
  <prosody rate="20%" pitch="+50%">
    <phoneme alphabet="x-sampa" ph="U">oo</phoneme>
    <break strength="none" />
  </prosody>
  <prosody rate="20%">
    <phoneme alphabet="x-sampa" ph="U">oo</phoneme>
  </prosody>
</speak>
```

However, when executed, Alexa applies her built-in inflection (to sound like a real human), and so the tone is not flat. These "ooh" sounds (above), for example, each have a falling tone. (They also have a noticeable break between phonemes even tho "no break" was explicitly specified.)

So then, **how did the Alexa voice which is heard singing all of those songs get programmed?** Was it via tools currently only available to Amazon developers?

It's also perplexing to me that I am apparently the only person on the internet even asking this question (based on zero results in stackoverflow, google, etc), especially this late in the game. Aren't there loads of musicians out there who would love to be able to make Alexa sing whatever they want?

Edit: Guys, I thought it was common knowledge, but [there is no human voice actor](https://www.quora.com/Whose-voice-is-on-Amazon-Alexa) behind Alexa. Her voice is completely computer-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa's voice is completely computer generated and so are the songs. Research is on-going into generating a singing synthesizer model ([#1](https://www.amazon.science/blog/a-simpler-singing-synthesis-system) and [#2](https://www.amazon.science/publications/singing-synthesis-with-a-little-help-from-my-attention)).

Here's a video by Popgun Labs regarding [how they make their AI sing](https://youtu.be/cd4f4i3HQ4w). Although I am unable to find how Amazon and Google do this, my guess it will be something similar.

*EDIT*: My earlier answer was based on an extension page and drew incorrect inconclusions.

Comment: But considering that Alexa's voice is computer-generated / doesn't come from any particular human, how can these songs be "recorded"?

Comment: @jdunk Yes, it is completely computerised, however, research has not advanced enough that Alexa can sing songs so those are pre-recorded. It's similar to how you can pay extra to get a celebrity's voice on your Alexa.

Comment: It would be impossible to get a human to record every known word and their combination.

Comment: Those celebrity voices are 1) from real humans and 2) don't sing, right? Are you saying that a real human is hired, is recorded singing, and then the recording of this real human voice is somehow changed to sound like Alexa's voice?

Comment: My first statement is probably misdirected since it comes from a page run by an extension provided by a third party. Let me try to find more about it and then answer this back.

Comment: @jdunk Updated the answer to reflect my latest research.

Answer (score 0):

My prediction would be either something really fancy like Natural Language Processing or something around that lines, AI/ML or they just had the voice actor sing out something or sing particular tones and just cut them together, i don't own an Alexa but i do have a HomePod mini and an iPhone and the way it pronounces our local singer names like "sidhu moosewala" or "amrit maan" (off topic but still related) i believe they just cut and put together words in a "clean" and 'flowing" way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps her voice is simply *autotuned*.

Certainly, pitch-shifting tools can force any desired pitch from any audio source, and I presume such tools can force duration changes as well.